# how to create a checkbox array in vba

Tags: vba

as I try to create a check box array for  for-loop using but I've got error 91, can any one can give me some suggestion to solve this? thx for help

```
Sub checkBoxSet()

    Dim activeSheet As Worksheet
    Set activeSheet = ActiveWorkbook.activeSheet
    Dim control(1 To 5) As CheckBox
     control(1) = Sheet1.CheckBox1 'star error 91 here
     control(2) = Sheet1.CheckBox2
     control(3) = Sheet1.CheckBox3
     control(4) = Sheet1.CheckBox4
     control(5) = Sheet1.CheckBox5

    For i = LBound(control) To UBound(control)
    ' copy the old sheet checkbox to new sheet
        activeSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(control(i).Left, control(i).Top, control(i).Width, control(i).Height).Select
             With Selection
                .Caption = ""
                .Value = xlOff
                .LinkedCell = "C" & ToRow
                .Display3DShading = False
            End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

[update : 5/3/2016 23:05 HKT]
pls accept me forgot to provide the background about this code, as here, it have two excel file, call temp.xlsm and month.xls, as the temp will copy a part of data to month.xls, also this part is about copy the checkbox to the month.xls, in temp.xlsm, it have 5 sheet, and the sheet1 is code name of the main sheet .

Comment: Need to use Set when assigning objects.  Als you do not need to set ActiveSheet - there's only ever one of these per instance of Excel.

Comment: Hi tim, your suggestion i've try before, I try to put set for every control, but it got another error that around 10xx or15xx.etc (sorry that i'm in the street), is there any reason to make it can solve?

Comment: What type of checkboxes are they? Forms or ActiveX ?

Comment: hi tim, I don't know... may be ActiveX, as I got it on the developer bar... also, this form I'am not the owner... so that I don't know the detail

Comment: wait. what "form"? you didn't mention any form in your question. are those checkboxes in a sheet or in a form?

Comment: ok, i get it, the check box is on the sheet1 worksheet

Answer (score 1):

"Sheet1" must be set (some `"ThisWorkBook.Sheets(1)"` or`"ThisWorkBook.Sheets(Sheet1)"`?)

declare control() variable as of `Shape` type and then get chekboxes in the old sheet as items of its `Shapes` collection

something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkBoxSet()
Dim i As Integer
Dim control(1 To 5) As Shape

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxOldSheet")
    Set control(1) = .Shapes("CheckBox1")
    Set control(2) = .Shapes("CheckBox2")
    Set control(3) = .Shapes("CheckBox3")
    Set control(4) = .Shapes("CheckBox4")
    Set control(5) = .Shapes("CheckBox5")
End With

' copy the old sheet checkbox to new sheet
With activeSheet
    For i = LBound(control) To UBound(control)
        With .CheckBoxes.Add(control(i).Left, control(i).Top, control(i).Width, control(i).Height)
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
'            .LinkedCell = "C" & ToRow
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

or you can make it more flexible like follows

```
Sub checkBoxSet2()
Dim shp As Variant

' copy the old sheet checkbox to new sheet
With activeSheet
    For Each shp In GetShapes(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CheckBoxOldSheet"), "CheckBox")
        With .CheckBoxes.Add(shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Width, shp.Height)
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
    '            .LinkedCell = "C" & ToRow
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
    Next shp
End With

End Sub


Function GetShapes(ws As Worksheet, shpNamePart As String) As Shape()
Dim foundShps() As Shape, shp As Shape
Dim nShp As Integer

With ws
    ReDim foundShps(1 To .Shapes.Count)
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        If shp.name Like shpNamePart & "*" Then ' <== adapt your name pattern to your needs
            nShp = nShp + 1
            Set foundShps(nShp) = shp
        End If
    Next shp
End With
ReDim Preserve foundShps(1 To nShp)

GetShapes = foundShps
End Function
```

where you get all shapes from a worksheet provided their name follows a pattern

Comment: "ThisWorkbook" is the workbook where the macro resides. Does it actually have a worksheet named "sheet1"?

Comment: year, I conform that

Comment: I tested it with no problems. Step through your code and use immediate window to query all relevant variables values when you hit the offending statement. for instance you could type "?ThisWorkbook.name" to see which workbook you'r referring to. and then "?ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count" to see how many sheets it has and finally "?ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).name" to see first worksheet name and then just change the index from 1 to the number you got previuosly

Comment: sorry, I forgot that this sub is in the module, will it make any error because not on the sheet?

Comment: the sub can stay in the module. do those other ckeckings I suggested and let me know. or explain in clear detail what's the background you're acting in (how many workbooks involved and its names, how many sheets has each of those workbooks and their names, which sheet do checkboxes reside in). or upload your project

Comment: I set up a "temp.xlsm" workbook, having a worksheet named "sheet1" with checkboxes and a VBA module with "Sub checkBoxSet()". I also set up a "month.xlsx" workbook. Then I tried calling "checkBoxSet()" from a button in a "month.xlsx" sheet: it worked, copying all chekboxes from "temp" "sheet1" to the "month" sheet where the button is. I also tried calling "checkBoxSet()" from a button in one of "temp" workbook sheets: it worked, copying checkboxes in the "temp" sheet where the button is. no errors at all. Are you actually trying one of my subs? who/where/how is calling the sub from?

Comment: hi, may be I got a wrong way, as I can copy my checkbox though the excel interface on the design mode enable, I thing same problem are happen on my macro code..., so that, thx for your help, may be I try on that way