# How to define Array of checkboxes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I know similar questions have been asked before like [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?530791-Excel-VBA-CheckBox-Control-Array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810516/how-to-create-a-checkbox-array-in-vba)
but I was having issues with initializing the checkbox array object (My VBA is quite rusty).

I have the following code:

```
Dim chkAdQ(4) As Checkbox

Set chkAdQ(0) = chkAdQ1
Set chkAdQ(1) = chkAdQ2
Set chkAdQ(2) = chkAdQ3
Set chkAdQ(3) = chkAdQ4
```

where chkAdQ1, chkAdQ2 etc. are ActiveX checkboxes present on the form. On debugging I can see that chkAdQ(4) prompts 'nothing' on the declaration itself and hence the assignment gives a Type mismatch exception.

I also tried by declaring chkAdQ(4) as an Object but to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: You  have  not  set  chkAdQ(4) ,  so  that is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim chkAdQ(0 To 3) As Variant

Set chkAdQ(0) = chkAdQ1
Set chkAdQ(1) = chkAdQ2
Set chkAdQ(2) = chkAdQ3
Set chkAdQ(3) = chkAdQ4
```

Comment: of all the things I had to try Variant was the one I missed . Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You can add all checkboxes on the worksheet quite nicely with a simple loop

```
Sub AddCheckBoxesToArray()
    Dim chkAdQ As Variant
    Dim cb

    i = 0
    ReDim chkAdQ(i)
    For Each cb In Sheet2.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(cb.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            If i > 0 Then ReDim Preserve chkAdQ(0 To i)
            Set chkAdQ(i) = cb
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cb

    For Each cb In chkAdQ
        Debug.Print cb.Name
    Next cb
End Sub
```

Remove the second loop when using. This is just to prove that they have all been added by printing their names to the Immediate window